# Featured Image / Post Thumbnail Cropping Query

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am building a site which can be viewed here: http://inspiredworx-labs.com/sites/garyarnold/

As you will see on the homepage, I have a grid, the site is responsive so am using % over px for widths.
You will see that the featured images are different in sizes. I have used this in my functions.php file:

```
add_image_size('thumb-700', 700, 394, true); // the_post_thumbnail('thumb-700');
```

I want all the images to be the same size; what am I doing wrong?

Note, I want the images to be 700px wide for when the screen size gets smaller.

Thanks in advance.

**Answered:**

My issue was down to some images being smaller than the required width and/or height. 
Something so simple but I hope it helps others in the future.

Comment: Did the images already exist before you defined the custom image size? If so, have you *regenerated thumbnails* for existing images?

Comment: I uploaded them but have Regenerated them several times during testing to try and get them to display correctly. The images are all of different sizes/dimensions originally, some the same but there is a good mixture.

Comment: Are all the images at least 700x394?

Comment: I have faced a similar issue. can u make sure all the images loaded has a image size greater equal to 700X394 that means it should be atleast 700X394?

Comment: Doh! It was to do with smaller sized images. I used the WPTest data to test my site which contained some smaller images. I feel so silly missing that out! (http://wptest.io/) Thank you so much for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was down to some images being smaller than the required width and/or height. 
Something so simple but I hope it helps others in the future.